# discount codes and tax calculations

Tags: tax, discount, totals, grand-total

I have a problem with discount codes and taxes, I just cannot get it to result in the correct values.

**Settings:**

- I have a tax of 25% on my site.
- The tax is already applied to the price of the products.
- I have a product in my basket worth 120
- I have a 30% discount code

**Intended result:**
Subtotal: 120
Discount: -36
Total: 84
Tax: 16.8

**Tried everything**
I have now tried every combination possible to have this outcome, but no matter which settings I pair together, one of the values is wrong.

The closest I can come is through:

- Apply Customer Tax: Before Discount
- Apply Discount on Prices: Excluding Tax

This combination provides the wrong discount value in frontend, but it is purely cosmetic as the calculations and the total are done correctly:
Subtotal: 120
*Discount: -29*

Total: 84
Tax: 16.8

This approach however does not work with fixed discount values.

Is there something I am missing? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check System - Configuration - Sales - Tax - Calculation where you can set

- Catalog prices include tax
- Shipping prices include tax

and set them to the correct options for your store.